# How can i add an image with swing and how do i make it the size of my window?

Tags: java, swing, window, size, imageicon

I tried to add an image to my window and make it the same size as the window but the project won't run and no image comes up, when I had the image working before it wouldn't be the size of the screen even thought I used `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` which is what I used for the window.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static int WIDTH = 1000;
    public static int HEIGHT = 368;

    public static JFrame window = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         CreateWindow();
    }

    public static void CreateWindow() {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        BackgroundImage();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void BackgroundImage() {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\SamBr\\Pictures\\image.png");
        window.add(image)
        image.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JLabel` to show your image and with `getScaledInstance()` method you can resize it.

```
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {

    public static int WIDTH = 1000;
    public static int HEIGHT = 368;

    public static JFrame window = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateWindow();
    }

    public static void CreateWindow() {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        BackgroundImage();
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void BackgroundImage() {
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\SamBr\\Pictures\\image.png");
        ImageIcon scaledImage = new ImageIcon(
                imageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(scaledImage);
        window.add(label);
    }

}
```